# I can't start Xubuntu 64bit! Xorg problem?? 

Tags: xubuntu, boot-failure

Is it possible that after using this command Xubuntu won't start?? I used it in order to change `Google Earth`'s appearance and when I restart I get a black screen and hangs there.
Is there any way to change what this command did. Btw, I am not 100% sure this was the reason but it was the only "strange" thing I did. Or perhaps restore to a previous point like winbugs?? I also upgraded my system (security and recommended upgrades only). Thanks in advance.

> gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme your-theme-name

I read some minutes ago something about that `xorg` thing causing problems. I remember that figured in the list of security fixes. How can I remove/fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The string you give changes a gnome setting for something. Since Xubuntu uses Xfce, not GNOME, it is possible the setting change is blocking the video display. I would use rescue mode and remove the change. If the desktop then works, you know not to use it again.

I also find sometimes, a complete power off and turn on again will clear these issues. It has taken as many as 6 times during some testing here to get it to work.

Comment: Could u be more specific?? How do I remove that change. I have no idea!! And... I'm not sure how can I use rescue mode. I'm new to linux. I also read that it is possible to repair the OS without making any changes to my personal files. Would that work??? I've got a xubuntu 12.04 64bit livecd. I turned off completely and didn't work. @charlie-tca

Comment: I did not replace "your-theme-name" I was sure I had to hahaah. So if I did not, that command cannot be the reason of the issue, can it?? @mateo_salta

Comment: That depends on what the command does. If the desktop is now looking for "your-theme-name" as a theme, it will not start.

Comment: Finally, I re-installed xubuntu. It was the fastest way to make my system work again, since installation does not take too long. The only thing I regret is that I had to download some programs again becuase I couldn't figure out how to keep them. For people like me that do not have much knowledge on OS, reinstalling turns to be a quick and easy solution. Probably not the best. Unlike my old win**** I didn't spend more than an hour or so to leave my dear Xubuntu just as it was before I screwed it up!! Thanks anyway charlie-tca.